# Replacing text in a file with datatable values

Tags: c#, file, stream

We have a sample text file with the text:

> The things God has prepared for those who love him

We read the text into datatable and assigned some values like this:

```
 The            1
----------
 things         2
----------
 God            3
----------
 has            4
----------
 prepared       5
----------
 for            6
----------
 those          7
----------
 who            8
----------
 love           9
----------
 him            10
----------
```

We're trying to replace the text in the input file with these corresponding numbers.
Is it possible? If possible, how can we do it?

Edit2:
we edited our code like this:

```
:
```

void replace()
        {

```
        string s1, s2;            
        StreamReader streamReader;
        streamReader = File.OpenText("C:\\text.txt");
        StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText("C:\\sample1.txt");
        int x = st.Rows.Count;
        int i1 = 0;                                       
            // Now, read the entire file into a string
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                {
                s1 = Convert.ToString(st.Rows[i]["Word"]);
                s2 = Convert.ToString(st.Rows[i]["Binary"]);
                s2+="000";
                char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', '\t' };
                string[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars);

                    // Write the modification into the same file 
                    string ab = words[i1]; // exception occurs here
                   // Console.WriteLine(ab);
                    streamWriter.Write(ab.Replace(s1, s2));
                    i1++;                                       
                }                
            }
        streamReader.Close();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
```

but we're getting an "Array index out of bounds" exception. we're unable to find the problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to use the same value if the word is repeated? Or just count the words?

Comment: yes. repeated words should have same value.

Comment: nope. not case sensitive

Comment: please post the exception including the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a bit of code to help you get going, it hasn't been extensively tested:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("sample1.txt", "The things God has prepared for those who love him the");

            string text = File.ReadAllText("sample1.txt").ToLower();
            var words = text
                .Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderByDescending(word => word.Length);

            var values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
            {
                values.Add(words.ElementAt(i), i + 1);
            }
            foreach (var kvp in values)
            {
                text = text.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString());
            }
            File.WriteAllText("sample1.txt", text);

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

it creates a test text file, reads it, converts it to lowercase, makes identifiers for distinct words, and replaces text based on those identifiers. long words are replaced before short words to offer a bit of bad replacement prevention.

**UPDATE:** I just noticed the question was updated and it's no longer an option to read the entire file in one string.. *sigh*.. so my answer only applies when you read and write all text in one go, maybe you can reuse parts of it when reading and writing per word.

Comment: Tnx for ur help. we edited the code, but we're getting the Array index out of bounds exception. we updated the question.